# Datetime format discrepancies between Ubuntu PHP servers

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, datetime, ubuntu

I have 2 servers, each running the exact same version of PHP (5.3.5-1ubuntu7.8).  They are also the exact same version of Ubuntu (11.04).  I have written a PHP script to connect to a SQL Server 2008 R2 database, select a datetime value, and print_r() it to the screen.

When I run the script on one server, the datetime is returned in this format: 2011-08-20 00:00:00.000.  When I run it on the other server, using the exact same script pulling from the same database record, I get this format: Aug 20 2011 12:00:00.000AM.

My problem is that I cannot figure out where the difference is on my servers that is causing the discrepancy in my datetime formats.  I have played around with the mssql.datetimeconvert setting in the php.ini files for both Apache and the CLI, to no avail.

Has anybody encountered this issue before and determined what causes it?  Any thoughts are extremely appreciated before I decide to just rebuild the servers. Thanks!

Comment: I've voted for this to be moved to ServerFault, if you're not interested in a programming solution.

Answer (score 0):

Does PHP not have the ability to format datetime values in a specific format? This is likely to do with local regional settings on the operating system rather than anything else, but you can always request a specific format from SQL Server instead of relying on PHP or the O/S to format them the same way by coincidence.

```
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), col, 120) + ' ' + CONVERT(CHAR(8), col, 108)
FROM dbo.table;
```

That said, PHP is probably the best place to do this, but I have to apologize - I'm not versed in PHP well enough to tell you how to do that (in C#, for example, you'd use `.Format()`).

From here:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php

Looks like instead of just dumping the string to the screen you should be using

```
echo date_format($date_var_from_rs, 'Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

As for the default formats on your Ubuntu servers, this blog post might be useful as well:

http://ccollins.wordpress.com/2009/01/06/how-to-change-date-formats-on-ubuntu/

Comment: Aaron, thanks for your fast reply.  While using SQL to convert the datetimes to the correct format is a good solution in the future, we have a bunch of applications that would require numerous changes to standardize our queries.  It also doesn't really identify what is the underlying server configuration problem. I tried checking the locale settings on both machines and they are the same.  Also, the datetime format code requires you to either know how the string is formatted ahead of time (which we do not, hence the problem) or to have a DateTime object, which we do not.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Did you follow the link to the blog post by ccollins? Your question about Ubuntu date formats specifically are probably a better fit for ServerFault. If you want a programming solution, then you're in the right place.

Comment: What do you mean, you do not have a DateTime object? Is the data stored in the database as a string???

Comment: The data is stored in the database with a datetime datatype, however, using PHP to connect to SQL server using a Linux driver will return datetime values as strings.  It appears that you only get DateTime objects back from queries on Windows.

Comment: And PHP has no ability to convert a string to a datetime?

Comment: It does, using the command you provided earlier, but that is the underlying problem here.  I'm getting a string back from the database and I cannot rely on what the format is going to be from server to server.  Therefore I cannot write one piece of code that will reliably parse dates on both machines.

Comment: If you force your SQL query to push out a string, using the CONVERT, then the *same* string should be provided on both servers. Did you TRY it?

Comment: I realize that solution will work and we have tried it, the issue is that I will have to make that change in several hundred queries (anywhere that is using a datetime) and am instead trying to determine what is broken about my servers.

Comment: Ok, so the problem isn't that you want one piece of code that will reliably parse dates on both machines, the problem is that you want a solution that doesn't require changing any code at all. That's fine, but you've exhausted my knowledge and set of suggestions, which are limited mostly to the code side. So if you don't want to change any code, I think you should ask your question on serverfault where there may be more Ubuntu experts who can help with server settings issues rather than code issues.

Comment: Thanks for trying, Aaron.  I have moved the question over to serverfault, per your suggestion.  The post is here: http://serverfault.com/questions/396182/sql-server-datetime-discrepancies-between-ubuntu-php-servers